# This mouseover() to access href and src links only results in "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"? Would like to access href and src via mouseover()

Tags: html, jquery, href, mouseover, onmouseover

I want to create an mouseover function that accesses href and src links. Yet all I get is the error, "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "Your file couldn’t be accessed. It may have been moved, edited or deleted.".

HTML code:

```
    
     <p><a href=https://readcomiconline.li/Comic/Punisher-Soviet/Issue-2?id=164726#18>OhGod.</p> 
     <p><a href=http://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/shop/index.php?l=product_detail&p=45>Oh man</a></p>`

 </body>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery code:

```
$("a").mouseover(function(){
  location.assign($("a"));
   });
});
```

How do I access the href and src links via mouseover as though I clicked on them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to close your 1st anchor tag with an `</a>`

Now, to get the href value, simply put this inside of your mouseover function:

```
$(this).getAttribute("href");
```

You can assign it to a variable ( *myLink = $(this).getAttribute("href");* ) or do whatever you want with it.